# Issues with deprecated NFC (RFID) Plugin with NativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript, nfc

I will start programming a mobile application for Android tablets on NativeScript Vue. I wanted to test the NFC plugin but it seems like it is too old.

Here is the repository of the plugin:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nfc

I implemented a method into my app to check if the plugin works. But in the background on NativeScript Sidekick I'm getting few errors.

> LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: '\'NativeScript-Vue has 
>    "Vue.config.silent" set to true, to see output logs set it to false.\''
>    LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: '\'Yes\''
>    LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: An uncaught Exception occurred on 
>    "main" thread.
>    Calling js method run failed
>    Error: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 
>    10155 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.
>      android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2029)
>      android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1975)
>      android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch(INfcAdapter.java:1012)
>      android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1648)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>      com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>      com.tns.gen.java.lang.Runnable.run(Runnable.java:17)
>      android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>      android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>
> StackTrace:
>    Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/vendor.js', line: 672, column: 31
>    Frame: function:'invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js', line: 19, column: 45
>    Frame: function:'run', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js', line: 23, column: 7
>    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>    at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Runnable.run(Runnable.java:17)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10155 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.
>    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2029)
>    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1975)
>    at android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch(INfcAdapter.java:1012)
>    at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1648)
>    ... 14 more
>   LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: '\'NativeScript-Vue has "Vue.config.silent" set to true, to see output logs set it to false.\''
>   LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: '\'OnTagDiscovered listener added\''
>   LOG from device Galaxy Tab Active2: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   Calling js method run failed
>   Error: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10155 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.
>      android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2029)
>      android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1975)
>      android.nfc.INfcAdapter$Stub$Proxy.setForegroundDispatch(INfcAdapter.java:1012)
>      android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1648)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>      com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>      com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>      com.tns.gen.java.lang.Runnable.run(Runnable.java:17)
>      android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>      android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>      com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

This code works on my tablet it's in the implemented method as I mentioned above.

```
nfc.available().then(
  function(avail) {
    console.log(avail ? "Yes" : "No");
  }
```

I get the message "YES" in the console.

```
[19-08-02 15:27:52.337] (CLI) (node:18276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
    at PreviewAppController.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:130:64)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:10:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:99:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:140:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:82:32)
[19-08-02 15:27:52.340] (CLI) (node:18276) TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
    at PreviewAppController.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:130:64)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:10:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:18276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at emitDeprecationWarning (internal/process/promises.js:113:13)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:106:3)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:140:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:82:32)
[19-08-02 15:32:26.783] (CLI) (node:18276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
    at PreviewAppController.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:130:64)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\lib\controllers\preview-app-controller.js:10:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
    at emitWarning (internal/process/promises.js:99:15)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:140:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:82:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is that plugin deprecated / too old if I literally updated it 30 days ago?

Please report issues on the Github repo as usual, along with a project that shows the issue so I can reproduce it.

Follow up: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-nfc/issues/44